# POST request in NODEJS stays undefined

Tags: node.js, http, post

I'm trying to get a JSON object into a variable, to display the time people have to wait in a facebook chatbot in a string. I tried various ways and also tried all the other ways i found on stack overflow or blog post but it just keeps returning undefined.

```
var waitingTime = request.post(
    "https://mypage.com/data/data/responsetime",
    {
        form: {
          'key': 'value'
        }
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            JSON.parse(body.responsetime)
            console.log(response)
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Check `error` and the response to see if there was an error during request or may be the response is not 200

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you really wrote `JSON.parse(body.responetime)` instead of `JSON.parse(body.responsetime)` (you misspelled `responsetime`) but it can cause your `undefined` problem! PS: I edited your post thinking this was a mistake (I hope it was :P).

Even if that's not the problem, I think your code is almost right. But you must understand how `request` works and also how callbacks work. When you use `request.post()`, you're doing an asynchronous call, it means that you have to wait the end of the process if you want the result. That's why you give a function as the third parameter of `request.post(address, data, callback)`.

Next, if you want to initialize your `var waitingTime`, you must initialize it in the callback:

```
var waitingTime = null;

request.post(
    "https://mypage.com/data/data/responsetime",
    {
        form: {
          'key': 'value'
        }
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            waitingTime = JSON.parse(body.responsetime);
            // Now you can use the waitingTime variable.
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, yeah i noticed the spelling error! But that wasn't it, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Cool :) I hope my solution will fix your problem. Do you understand now how the `callbacks` are working ? If you need more details I can take 5 more minutes to explain :)